# UISearchDisplayController tableView doesn't fire prepareForSegue

Tags: objective-c

What am I doing wrong?

I have 2 tableViewControllers. One of them works fine. When I do a search the result is displayed with the accessory button on the right, and the prepareForSegue works well.

But the other tableViewController is exactly the same as the first one. The search works fine but doesn't display the accessory button, and the prepareForSegue is not fired.

Can't figure out what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
         [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowComment" sender:self];
     }
}
```

I still don't get it why prepareForSeque doesn't fire for searchDisplay tableview.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time looking through this as well. I had the exact same problem, and I'm not using story boards for this particular build because I programmatically added the search to the navigation bar. It all came down to one simple thing, add this:

[searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDelegate:self]

Once I did that, then didSelectRowAtIndexPath finally fired for selecting a result from my searchResults tableView!